# Where is the error in solving this simple ODE with the Dirac delta impuslse and Heaviside step function?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, step-function

I am trying to solve the following ODE:

$$ {dT(\tau) \over d \tau} + \rho ^2 T(\tau)+a H(m\tau-d) + b \delta(m\tau-d)=0 \tag1 $$

where $\rho$, $a$, $b$, $m$, and $d$ are constants, $H$ is the Heaviside step function, and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution. Here is what I have tried. First I wrote:

$$ T(\tau)= e^{-\rho^2 \tau} \alpha(\tau) \tag 2 $$

I inserted equation $(2)$ into expression $(1)$ and obtained:

$$ {d \alpha (\tau) \over d \tau} = -e^{\rho^2 \tau} \Big ( aH(m\tau-d) + b \delta(m\tau-d) \Big ) \tag 3$$

Next, I divided equation $(3)$ with $-a$:

$$ -{1 \over a}{d \alpha (\tau) \over d \tau} = e^{\rho^2 \tau} \Bigg ( H(m\tau-d) + {b \over a} \delta(m\tau-d) \Bigg ) \tag 4$$

To simplify the problem, I used the following scaling factors:

$$ \tau = {t \over \rho^2} \tag 5 $$
$$ \alpha = -{a \over \rho^2} \beta \tag 6$$

and obtained:

$$ {d \beta(t) \over d t} = e^t \Bigg ( H \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) + {b \over a} \delta \Bigg({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) \Bigg ) \tag 7$$

Now I have the following integral equation to solve:

$$ \beta(t) = \int e^t H \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) dt + {b \over a} \int e^t \delta \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) dt \tag 8$$

Both integrals can be solved using the integration-by-parts method. Using:

$$ U =  H \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) \tag 9$$
$$ dV =  e^t dt \tag{10}$$

I have obtained the following:

$$ dU = {m \over \rho^2} \delta \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) dt\tag{11}$$
$$ V =  e^t \tag{12}$$

which enabled me to write:

$$ \int e^t H \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) dt = e^t H \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) - {m \over \rho^2}\int e^t \delta \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) dt \tag{13}$$

Similarly, using:

$$ U =  \delta \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) \tag{14}$$
$$ dV =  e^t dt \tag{15}$$

I have obtained the following:

$$ dU = -{\Bigg( {m \over \rho^2} \Bigg)}^2 dt \tag{16}$$
$$ V =  e^t \tag{17}$$

Now I can solve the integral:

$$ \int e^t \delta \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) dt= e^t \delta \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) + {\Bigg( {m \over \rho^2} \Bigg)}^2 \int e^t dt = e^t \Bigg(\delta \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t - d \Bigg) + {\Bigg( {m \over \rho^2} \Bigg)}^2 \Bigg) + C \tag{18}$$

where $C$ is the integration constant. Equation $(8)$ now becomes:

$$ \beta(t) = e^t \Bigg( H \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t-d \Bigg) + \Bigg( {b \over a} - {m \over \rho ^2}\Bigg) \Bigg(\delta \Bigg ({m \over \rho^2}t - d \Bigg) + {\Bigg( {m \over \rho^2} \Bigg)}^2 \Bigg) + C \tag{19}$$

By re-scaling, I have obtained:

$$\alpha (\tau) = -{a \over \rho ^2} e^{\rho^2 \tau} \Bigg( H \Bigg ({m}\tau-d \Bigg) + \Bigg( {b \over a} - {m \over \rho ^2}\Bigg) \Bigg(\delta \Bigg ({m}\tau - d \Bigg) + {\Bigg( {m \over \rho^2} \Bigg)}^2 \Bigg) -{a \over \rho ^2} C \tag{20} $$

Finally, I have obtained the solution to be:

$$ T(\tau) = -{a \over \rho ^2} \Bigg( H \Bigg ({m}\tau-d \Bigg) + \Bigg( {b \over a} - {m \over \rho ^2}\Bigg) \Bigg(\delta \Bigg ({m}\tau - d \Bigg) + {\Bigg( {m \over \rho^2} \Bigg)}^2 \Bigg) -{a \over \rho ^2} C e^{-\rho^2 \tau} \tag{21}$$

The problem is, when I tried to verify my solution, I noticed it was wrong. The derivative of the above solution is:

$$ {dT(\tau) \over d \tau} = -m{a \over \rho ^2} \Bigg(  \delta \Bigg ({m}\tau-d \Bigg) - \Bigg( {b \over a} - {m \over \rho ^2}\Bigg) \Bigg ) +a C e^{-\rho^2 \tau} \tag{22}$$

Inserting this into equation $(1)$ does not give zero. It gives:

$$ a{m \over \rho^2} \Bigg( {b \over a} - {m \over \rho^2} \Bigg) \Bigg( 1 - {m \over \rho^2} \Bigg)\tag{23}$$

It would be of great help to me if someone would point out my errors so I can obtain the correct solution. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Suppose that the solution is:

$$
T(\tau)=T(0)e^{-\rho^2\tau}-\frac{1}{m}H(m\tau-d)\left[\frac{am}{\rho^2}\left(1-e^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)}\right)+be^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)} \right] \tag{24}
$$

The derivative of the above function is:

$$ {dT(\tau) \over d \tau} = -\rho^2T(0)e^{-\rho^2\tau}-
 \delta(m \tau - d) \left[\frac{am}{\rho^2}\left(1-e^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)}\right)+be^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)} \right] 
-\frac{1}{m}H(m\tau-d)\left[{am}\left(e^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)}\right)-\rho^2 be^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)} \right]
\tag{25}$$

Plugging $(24)$ and $(25)$ into $(1)$ gives:

$$  
-\rho^2T(0)e^{-\rho^2\tau}-
 \delta(m \tau - d) \left[\frac{am}{\rho^2}\left(1-e^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)}\right)+be^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)} \right] 
-\frac{1}{m}H(m\tau-d)\left[{am}e^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)}-\rho^2 be^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)} \right]
+
\rho^2T(0)e^{-\rho^2\tau}-\frac{\rho^2}{m}H(m\tau-d)\left[\frac{am}{\rho^2}\left(1-e^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)}\right)+be^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)} \right]
+ a H(m\tau-d) + b \delta(m\tau-d) =
\delta(m\tau-d) 
\left[\left(b-\frac{am}{\rho^2}\right) \left(1-e^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)}\right) \right] \tag{26}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating a simple thing. The solution to Eq. $(3)$ is (assuming $m>0$ and $d>0$)
\begin{align}
\alpha(\tau)&=\alpha(0) - \int_0^{\tau}e^{\rho^2 t} \left( aH(mt-d) + b \delta(mt-d) \right) dt \\
&=\alpha(0) - \int_0^{m\tau}e^{\rho^2 u/m} \left( aH(u-d) + b \delta(u-d) \right)
\frac{du}{m} \\
&=\alpha(0)-\frac{1}{m}H(m\tau-d)\left[\frac{am}{\rho^2}\left(e^{\rho^2\tau}-e^{\rho^2 d/m}\right)+be^{\rho^2 d/m} \right],
\end{align}
hence
$$
T(\tau)=T(0)e^{-\rho^2\tau}-\frac{1}{m}H(m\tau-d)\left[\frac{am}{\rho^2}\left(1-e^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)}\right)+be^{-\rho^2(\tau- d/m)} \right].
$$

Comment: Hello Goncalo. Thank you for your comment. The thing is, I keep getting a residual when plugging your solution in equation $(1)$. I will write in my question the process of how I got it.

Comment: I noticed that what I wrote in my EDIT, in the end, is actually zero because the exponential function is equal to one at $\tau = d/m$ which is the only moment that the delta distribution is not equal to zero. Thank you very much.